# Linux system call getifaddr c++

Tags: c++, linux, system-calls

in my c++ application I've wrriten this code:

```
struct ifaddrs *ifap;

if (0 != getifaddrs(&ifap)) {
    error = errno;
    return -1;
}

addresses.clear();
for (struct ifaddrs *ifa = ifap; ifa; ifa = ifa->ifa_next) {
    sockaddr *s=ifa->ifa_addr;
    PRINT(" LocalIP sockaddr %u.%u.%u.%u \n",s->sa_data[2],s->sa_data[3],s->sa_data[4],s->sa_data[5]);}
```

when I debug the print I see that when I have static ip like 10.0.0.12 it prints it correct. but ip from DHCP like 192.168.14.12 it prints it "-64.-88.14.12"

how can I solve this issue?

10x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change %d's to %hhu's.

%d is signed integer.
%u is unsigned integer.
%hhu is unsigned char.

This code shows why:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
        char i = 192;
        printf("%u, %hhu, %d", i,i,i);
}
```

Output: `4294967232, 192, -64`

Comment: when I changed it to %u I get instead of: 192.168.14.12 I get: 4294967232.4294967208.14.12

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's trying to print bytes as signed. Try using %u instead of %d inside IP address.

Comment: when I changed it to %u I get instead of: 192.168.14.12 I get: 4294967232.4294967208.14.12